# How is schoolbook long division an O(n^2) algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, math

**Premise:**

> This [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) suggests that
>   the computational complexity of
>   ["Schoolbook" long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) is
>   **O(n^2)**.

**Deduction:**

> Instead of taking two n-digit
>   numbers, if I take one n-digit number
>   and one m-digit number, then the
>   complexity would be **O(n*m)**.

**Contradiction:**

> Suppose you divide 100000000 (n
>   digits) by 1000 (m digits), you get 100000, which takes **six steps** to
>   arrive at.
>
> Now, if you divide 100000000 (n
>   digits) by 10000 (m digits), you get 10000. Now this takes only **five steps**.

**Conclusion:**

> So, it seems that the order of
>   computation should be something like
>   **O(n/m)**.

**Question:**

> Who is wrong, me or Wikipedia, and
>   where?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are wrong, and it is because you are not counting operations on every digit.  Instead, you're counting as if you can do a subtraction on a N-digit number in O(1).  In general, you can't; it takes O(N).

Comment: @Rex Kerr: I did not understand the "not counting operations on every digit" part. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Suppose you are computing 152 / 24.  You first have to compute 6*24 = (6*4) + (6*20) = (20 + 4) + (100 + 20) = 100 + (20+20) + 4 = 144.  Then you have to compute 152 - 144 = (100 - 100) + (50 - 40) + (2-4) = 10 + (-2) = (10-2) = 8.  Note how we have an operation for _every digit_ in the number (in the subtraction step, it's one subtraction for every digit).

Comment: thanks! So, if I divide a n digit number by a m digit number, O(m) for multiplication, O(m) for subtraction, and this repeated O(n) times. So, order ~ O(n*(m+m)) = O(n*m). This reduces to O(n^2) for division of a n digit number by another n digit number (not only by substituting m by n, but also by following the whole procedure again). Now I have some idea how that O(n^2) was arrived at.

Answer (score 6):

Try is again with numbers like 12341234 and 43214321.

Big O is the limiting complexity for all cases, not for a particularly easy one.

Answer (score 2):

I think (haven't proved, so not sure) that your deduction is a true statement, but it doesn't actually follow from your premise. If all you know is that dividing two n-digit numbers is O(n^2), all you can deduce about an n- and an m-digit number is that it is O(max(n,m)^2), not that it is O(n*m). That's because an n digit number can also be considered an n+1 digit number with a leading 0, replacing the operation with one that we know the complexity of.

For example which is not O(n*m): using long multiplication, calculating A^2 + B^2 is O(n^2) if A and B are n-digit numbers. However, it is not O(n*m) if A is n digits and B is m digits. To see this, fix B=1, hence m=1 and note that calculating A^2 + 1 by long multiplication certainly is not O(log(A))[*].

Your "contradiction" does not contradict either your premise or your deduction. Big-O notation is about asymptotic behaviour as something tends to infinity. The fact that f(3) = 12 for some function f tells you absolutely nothing about big-O limits for f. Even if f(n) = 12 for all odd n, that still tells you nothing about big-O estimates, because you don't know how fast the function grows on even numbers. The existence of fast special cases doesn't mean the function is fast.

[*] Actually, I've made an abuse of notation myself, there. If a two-variable function f(n,m) is O(n*m), it doesn't follow (as I've suggested), that f(n,1) is O(n). But it does follow that for sufficiently large m, f(n,m) is O(n), so replace 1 with "some large constant or other".

Comment: @Steve Jessop: What is `O(log(A))`? Shouldn't it be O(n) (assuming  f(n,m) is O(n*m) =>  f(n,1) is O(n))? Is this some alternate notation that I am not aware of??

Comment: log is logarithm. If n is the number of digits in A, then log(A) is O(n), and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider this case:

> Sorting the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, ..... , 10000000]` takes exactly **one step**. Hardly `~nlogn` steps like you would expect from an optimal sorting algorithm.

The flaw in your logic is that Big-O is an asymptotic bound on *all* inputs. You can't take one easy input and deduce a contradiction from it.

Comment: It still requires at least n-1 comparisons to establish that the array is already sorted.  Also, Big-O notation doesn't *necessarily* refer to the worst-cast.  It can also be used to describe the average case or even the best case asymptotic performance of an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Well the Cormen book says this:
Consider the ordinary "paper and pencil" algorithm for long division: dividing a by b,
which yields a quotient q and remainder r. Show that this method requires O((1 + lg q)
lg b) bit operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is O(N^2) due to all the multiplication and the subtraction plus the division that has to be done and as the numbers grows the running time needed increase in quadratic pattern due to that, e.g. 4/2 take one unit of time while 2342677/39 takes much much more time.