# What is the complexity of long-division?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

In lecture my professor was explaining the big-O time of various arithmetic operations. He told us that long-division is around O(n^2). Looking around online, it seems that this is correct, but why?

Can anyone go into detail in why long-division is in O(n^2) time?

Comment: Reviewing the integer division algorithm may shed some light on this for you. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quadratic in *the number of bits* of the numbers you're dividing, which means that to divide `n` by `m` you need `O((log max(m,n))^2)` time. This is because each subtraction takes `O(log max(m, n))` time.

An explanation is available [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486152/how-is-schoolbook-long-division-an-on2-algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, some definitions:

- division operation: dividend / divisor = quotient
- n = number of digits in the dividend
- m = number of digits in the divisor
- q = number of digits in the quotient

The generation of each digit of the quotient requires two operations:

1. Multiplication of the divisor by a single digit. This takes O(m) time.
2. Subtraction of that result from the dividend. This takes O(m) time. It doesn't depend on n because you don't need to subtract it from every digit of the dividend.

The computational complexity doesn't depend on the size of the dividend. For example, if you want to compute 1/3 to 5 places (.33333) it will take 5 iterations, but if you want to compute it to 20 places (.33333333333333333333) it will take 20 iterations.

The number of digits in the divisor is not actually a factor either. Say you want to compute 1/pi and you want the result to be accurate to 4 places. You don't need every digit of pi to compute this (which is convenient, because there are a lot!). You can ignore all but first few (where a few is approximately q) digits of the divisor. In this case, it is sufficient to use the 4 most significant digits of pi to get 1/pi accurate to 4 places: 1/3.141 ~= 0.3183  (for context, 1/pi with 20 digits of accuracy is 0.31830988618379067153).

Therefore you need q iterations, and there is O(q) work in each iteration, so the computational complexity of long division is O(q^2).